# How do I use a outputstream object to insert records in a database.

Tags: java, outputstream

I have access to a Java library that let's me pass it an OutputStream object and it writes a report to it. The reports consists of data, each column is delimited by tabs and each record is on a new row i.e. separated by newline. Currently I am passing it a fileOutput stream as below. I need to ultimately insert the data in a database. Instead of writing to a file, I wish to directly insert the data in a database. What is the best way to achieve this ?  To rephrase : I want to directly insert the data in the OutputStream to a database without having to first put it in a file. I am aiming for this with the assumption that it will improve performance.

```
        OutputStream report = null;
        try {
            report = new FileOutputStream( "report-" + sellerID + ".xml" );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         request.setReportOutputStream( report );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `FileOutputStream` (writing to an external file)
you can use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) (writing to a byte array in memory).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream report = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
request.setReportOutputStream(report);

// let request write into the OutputStream

byte[] byteArray = report.toByteArray();
```

After that you can write the `byteArray` into a database, or do what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to pass it a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (as per Thomas Fritsch's answer). This would be my choice if the data isn't too large. If it is, you don't want to run out of heap space by creating a gigantic intermediate byte array. You can, instead, write the data directly to the database as soon as it's written to the output stream by the report writer. To do this, you'll need to create your own special OutputStream:

```
public class DatabaseOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    // See the source code for ByteArrayOutputStream to see how to implement your class.
    // You'll basically need to write a record to the database every time you receive a
    // line separator.
}

OutputStream dbos = new DatabaseOutputStream(/*db connection params*/);
request.setReportOutputStream(dbos);
```